# Build failed with an exception?

Tags: android, exception

How to resolve this issue trying lot of Answer but not sucess.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  >   /home/nagarjuna-1383/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/nagarjuna-1383/ErosApp/Android_2_0/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/nagarjuna-1383/ErosApp/Android_2_0/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  >   Error Code:
  >   2
  >   Output:

  ```
  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzhb;
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
  ```

  - Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

`NOTE:` using Android studio for this.

Comment: i guess you added two different versions of support jars.

Comment: try deleting `app/build/intermediates` folder then close your IDE and re-open it.

Comment: am using Android studio for this.

Comment: @Rustam not useful same thing h append.

Comment: Have you checked the answers from this source: Conflict with nineoldandroids #201 https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/201 ?!

Comment: `Project -> Clean` and `Project -> Build` or `Project -> Rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove all folder on your project without src/res folder then import again in android studio. finally run project hopefully will get solution for this process